# How to teach rails form button submit to use remote?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, submit

The question has come up before in some postings,
but none of them has been specific and no solution was yet proposed.

I have a rails form.
I use 
I want to make this button to submit the form via ajax, aka remote:true.

It appears to me, that rails.js does not yet honor buttons of type submit,
it does not work for me, even if I add a data-remote tag to the button manually.
(While it should work with )

But I want to go the route with the new html5 button formaction attribute,
because this makes it so much easier to assign different actions to different buttons.

So I'm asking if I'm just missing something here,
or if this is just plain missing from rails ujs, yet?

I'm just digging in the rails.js now,
so maybe someone already came up with a patch?
to make the button type=submit remote:true work

Answer (score 2):

If I got you, you want to submit the form (not a special button press) via AJAX. For this, you add a `remote: true` to your `form`-tag, and not the button itself.

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that i understood your question... I had to explicitly submit a remote form (because a bug in chrome) the problem for me was that the form was data-remote but not the botton submit. Now i submit in the onclick of the botton but i have to use the submit method of the form itself.

Let be clearer... my form has the data-remote attribute to true and my submit botton has
 `:onclick => "stuff_i_had_to_do_before_submiting();$("new_id_of_my_form").submit();"`

hope it's help...

ps: thanks [pduersteler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/92096/pduersteler) for the formating

and yep "onclick" is not good but the stuff before ("stuff_i_had_to_do_before_submiting()" need some rubish and i pull the javascript in a separate file for reuse...

Comment: Watch your formatting. And take a read on unobtrusive javascript, because your answer reflects bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

I use to do this:

- add a class to the submit button which starts with "js-", it works as hook to retrieve the button in a little jquery script/plugin.
- in js I retrieve the button and do `preventDefault();`on it to avoid the submit
- optionally I can validate datas or display some kind of alerts/modals views etc
- last I call `$.ajax` to do the asycronous call

Here a little example

```
= f.submit 'myButton', class: 'js-my_async_form'
:javascript
  jQuery(function($) {
    $('.js-my_async_form').asyncSubmit();
 });
```

and here you have the "little plugin"

```
jQuery(function($) {
  jQuery.fn.asyncSubmit = function(){
    return this.each(function () {
      var mybutton = $(this);
      var completed = function(answer) {
        // do some stuff
      };

      var error = function(answer) {
        //do some stuff
      };

      var submit_click = function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
          url: //my_form_path,
          type: //get or post,
          success: completed,
          error: error,
          dataType: 'json'
        });
      }

      mybutton.click(submit_click);
    });
  }
});
```

It is and adaptation of my script so **handle with care!**